# Customizing Checkout in magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout

I am trying to add custom step in magento checkout process.

The first step is to show the cart page items table in the checkout.

Is is possible to show cart page items table in the first step of checkout?

I have attached the image here.

[image]

If anyone tried of it. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: That step is only for display purpose or do you want to do anything there?

Comment: @SukumarGorai, No the first step will be like full cart page. We can apply discount there, and update item n all

Comment: @jafarpinjar can you please tell me how did you solved the problem?

Comment: @skm, I am also looking for the solution.

Comment: @jafarpinjar it has been more than one year now!

Comment: @skm, Later our requirement changed, so couldn't check solution for this

Comment: @jafarpinjar oh I see.

Answer (score 0):

haven't tried it yet. but just to give you and idea you can customize the checkout page by overriding the **checkout_index_index.xml** from your module using below path:

> ***vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\layout checkout_index_index.xml***

Comment: yes, i have referred below link to add custom step in checkout, https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/add-custom-checkout-step-magento-2.html
I need to add cart page as the first step of checkout. Is that possible to add?

Answer (score 0):

We can define the sort order for the checkout steps. Easy for your [reference](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html).

http://nimb.ws/mlnDCI